# Can the new raspberry pi B+ act as a usb sniffer?

Tags: usb, peripherals

I am trying to capture data from a computer going to a USB peripheral. I think the previous raspberry pi (model B) couldn't do this because it could not act a USB slave. But can the new raspberry pi B+?

Also, I know the model B can't work if it is just plugged in the same USB hub, but can it work as a USB sniffer if I plug the computer into one port and the peripheral into another?

Comment: I doubt it. I'm assuming the B+ just has 2 hubs rather than 1, but still can't act as a USB slave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it. There weren't any real changes to the core components or software of the Pi, the SoC remains the same, as well as the chip driving the USB/Ethernet.

The changes were simply the extra USB ports, more GPIO, a new power circuit, a new port for audio/component video, and a redesigned board.

Thus, if the Model B didn't work, I don't think the Model B+ will either.