# USB Rx from GPIO

Tags: usb, rpi.gpio

I'm trying to get Rx from USB via GPIO for reverse engineering. I'll use it for such as keyboard, mouse, USB fax modem etc... I want to get data from USB device and sending data to my another computer. If it's impossible at least give me an idea or alternative way for doing this.

I tried to get keyboard's key presses but I failed at it.

Edit: in Python I already know how to key press or normal input set up but I think i'm lookin for digital input

I need a code block for doing this in Python for ex.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN)
while True:
    print(GPIO.input(18))
```

I connected a keyboard to USB Female and its always returning 1

[image]

SMFBE

Comment: Please edit in the entire program.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please note that your question is very broad and therefore hard to answer. Please be more specific.

Comment: I'll edit ASAP. Thanks for warnings and informations

Comment: have you considered using a USB monitor/analyzer netcat can do this.

Comment: related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32197/can-the-pi-emulate-an-hid-device-with-via-usb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All apologies for my (deleted) answer about USB using 5V logic.  I had assumed this was the case, but when I went to check that I [found this](http://www.eeherald.com/section/design-guide/esmod14.html), which says high is <=3.6V and low is >=0.3V.  I *think* this should be okay.

However, it also reads:

> A USB device pulls one of the data lines high with a 1.5kO resistor. **This overpowers one of the pull-down resistors in the host and leaves the data lines in an idle state called "J".** The choice of data line indicates a device's speed support; full-speed devices **pull D+ high**, while low-speed devices **pull D- high.** In fact the data is transmitted by toggling the data lines between the J state and the opposite K state.

Source: http://www.eeherald.com/section/design-guide/esmod14.html

I am sure USB is a more complicated protocol than your code implements.  Some initialization must take place.  The keyboard is not simply a dumb serial device, but you have presumed plugging it in that way and hitting a key will cause the levels to shift. You will need to go through the specification to determine what is actually going to happen.

I would guess if the proper initialization does not occur, the device may simply leave the line high and not transmit keystrokes, etc.  Notice if you plug a keyboard into a computer, it immediately recognizes it as a keyboard *before you hit any keys*.  How does that happen?  How does it know it is not a data stick or camera, etc?  It's via the USB protocol, and you have not implemented it.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I assume it's hard for me because i do not have electronic information yet. I'll do more research about this but if i be success, i'll write down here... Thanks and regards

Answer (score 2):

Um, you need more than what you have got, to connect directly to a USB device as you have tried.

For starters, USB data is carried *differentially* over a *pair* of data leads (D+ and D-) and whilst most of the time one is the inverse of the other the [voltage levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Signaling) (Wikipedia link) are 0.0-0.3V (low) and 2.8-3.6 (high) for low- (1.5Mbs) and full-speed (12Mbs) rates - and those are relative to each other - not to ground; high-speed uses ±0.10V (low) 0.36-0.44V (high) but again that is relative to each other NOT to ground so it is quite possible for the individual voltages to be **over the 3.3 Volt<sub>max</sub> for the GPIO pins!**

You have also only connected the Data+ line and not the Data- one but this is largely academic as your current circuit cannot IMHO work.

[image: A close up picture of part of the Qustioner's picture of their hardware - showing the connections made to a USB A connector plugged into a breadboard]

Don't give up hope yet, though: for your stated aim - to send/share USB with another computer - you may want to look for the `usbip` package and/or packages containing the phrase "usbredir"...

Comment: Thanks for informations and usbip mm.. it look interesting project thanks

Comment: USB is not a truly differential protocol, it cannot work without GND. D+ and D- signals in USB have maximum and minimum voltage levels defined (with GND as a reference), and it's safe to connect them to 3.3V devices.

Answer (score 0):

Above all, there's no such thing as "USB RX". USB is a strictly "Request-Response" protocol, you will never receive a reply without sending a request first. It's also quite complex: each device expects to be configured before it can be used. Even if you managed to generate correct D- and D+ signals, you'd have to implement a USB host controller driver for your approach to work.