# Mouse input to a PC with GPIO

Tags: mouse

I want to use the gpio pins on the pi too use it as a mouse for a PC. Can it be done? If yes then how? I want to use python.

Comment: Related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/271/19949 and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/32197/19949

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a Pi Zero (W), which can operate in the so-called USB gadget mode? The Pi Zero (W) then appears as a normal USB mouse/keyboard to the PC. Please note that this isn't possible with a Pi A/B, but only with the Zero Pis. Using USB gadget mode avoids having to emulate serial mouse, unless you have a really old PC system which hasn't USB support.

Comment: I don't have a Pi Zero