# Python HID API's for RPi's

Tags: python, pi-zero, emulation, hid

I realize that solutions exist for having an RPi emulate an HID device ([Can the Pi Emulate an HID device with via USB?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32197/can-the-pi-emulate-an-hid-device-with-via-usb)) but are there any existing API's that can achieve the same thing as https://github.com/adafruit/circuitpython but specifically for RPi's? Python would be most convenient then followed by Node.js

Thanks in advance for thoughts and insight!

Comment: What can CircuitPython achieve re HID emulation? I think to need to clarify what you want in more detail. BTW: it's possible to install CircuitPython on the Pi

Comment: CircuitPython appears to just make things easy using human-readable pseudo code instead of having to reference the byte data that needs to be sent to the HID device, imo. May I ask where it is documented that CircuitPython will work on a Pi? It is not listed as a supported board

Comment: Adafruit learning website: https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-on-raspberrypi-linux/overview . I have it installed in a virtual environment, but have only one a little test so far.

Comment: I tried to find what you just sent, idk how I how I missed it, thank you!

Comment: Do you know if these examples would work on a Pi0, @Dirk? https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/projects/hid/en/latest/examples.html

Comment: Sorry, I don't know