# Relay Bluetooth keyboard out as a USB keyboard

Tags: usb, bluetooth, keyboard, relay, input-device

I have a bluetooth keyboard that's originally connected to my desktop PC. The problem is that I can't use it in BIOS or to select different boot options at grub because the bluetooth drivers aren't loaded up yet at that point. I'm trying to use a Pi as a relay point where it will always have the bluetooth keyboard paired to it, take in the keyboard commands, then output it as a USB keyboard (it'll be connected to my desktop PC through USB).

I found this guide (among many others) that tries to do the opposite, but couldn't tell if I can flip it around.
https://www.gadgetdaily.xyz/emulate-a-bluetooth-keyboard-with-the-raspberry-pi/

Is there a known way to accomplish this? Is there a more straightforward method? (I'm new to raspberry pi and peripheral IO, but familiar with python and linux in general)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.

Comment: [This](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/32197/19949) might be of interest. I think investigating the Pi Zeros USB-Gadget mode is a way to go.

Comment: Thanks! I'll investigate some of the solutions in those discussions and post an answer if they work out.

Comment: Just found this in another post: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/raspberry-pi-zero-usb-keyboard-hid/

Comment: This looks pretty promising. It'll take me a bit to figure out what the different scripts do (prefer to do that before hooking it up to my system), then we can set up your response as an answer. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Adding links to solutions which directly address the OPs problem: Found this https://github.com/mikerr/pihidproxy And this: https://github.com/PixelGordo/bluetooth_2_hid Or this: https://github.com/ramius345/pizero-keyboard-proxy